# List and String formatting difficulties: importing a txt file, adding strings and writing it to a new file

Tags: python, string, list, formatting, file-writing

I'm having trouble with list and string formatting, and writing the changes to a new file. What I'm looking for is:

1. STRINGS BEFORE
2. imported txt file contents (a list of string values)
3. STRINGS AFTER

Where both the preceding and following STRINGS are already defined, and everything is written to a new file!

My end goal, is so that when i import a txt file (containing a list) and run the code, it then is printed to a new file with pre-defined strings added before and after the imported txt file's list.

My code right now is as follows:

```
text_file = open(r"text_file path", "r")
lines = text_file.read().split(',')
lines.insert(0, "String Values Before")
lines.insert("String Values After")
text_file.close()
lines.write("new_file.txt", "w+")
```

The problem now is that I am inserting to the list, whereas I want the strings to be separate to the list!

I've been able to produce what I want the written file to look like in the console with this code here:

```
FIRMNAME = "apple"
FILETYPE = "apple"
REPLYFILENAME = "apple"
SECMASTER = "apple"
PROGRAMNAME = "apple"

text_file = open(r"textfile path", "r+")
lines = text_file.readlines().split('\n')

print(("START-OF-FILE \nFIRMNAME= ") + FIRMNAME) 

print(("FILETYPE= ") + FILETYPE) 

print(("REPLYFILENAME= ") + REPLYFILENAME) 

print(("SECMASTER= ") + SECMASTER) 

print(("PROGRAMNAME= ") + PROGRAMNAME) 


print("START-OF-FIELDS")

print("END-OF-FIELDS")

print("START-OF-DATA")
pprint.pprint(lines) 
print("END-OF-DATA")
print("END-OF-FILE")
```

I just can't figure out how to write this to a new file! Help!

Comment: Use the append mode and a newline

Comment: What do you mean by this? Could you show me? Thanks! :)

Comment: `lines.write("new_file.txt", "a")`

Comment: and then you can append to the file like this: `file.append((("FILETYPE= ") + FILETYPE)+"\n" )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve it this way:

```
newFile = 'your_new_file.txt'
oldFile = 'your_old_file.txt'

# Open the new text file
with open(newFile, 'w') as new_file:
    # Open the old text file
    with open(oldFile, 'r') as old_file:
        # Write the line before the old content
        new_file.write('Line before old content\n')

        # Write old content
        for line in old_file.readlines():
            new_file.write(line)

        # Write line after old content
        new_file.write('Line after old content')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `lines` is of type `list`, which does not have a method `write`.
Furthermore `insert` requires a position, that your second call is lacking.

You'll need to read the file, concat it with the prefix and suffix values accordingly and then write it to the appropriate output file:

```
with open("text_file_path", "r") as input_file:
    text = input_file.read()

text = '\n'.join(("String Values Before", text, "String Values After"))

with open("new_file.txt", "w+") as output_file:
    output_file.write(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pformat`.
[pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html)

```
before_values = ["a", "b", "c"]
data = ["1", "2", "3"]
after_values = ["d", "e", "f"]
with open("outfile.txt", "w) as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(before_values)) # Write before values
    outfile.write(pprint.pformat(data))     # Write data list
    outfile.write("\n".join(after_values))  # Write after values
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error you originally call the `insert` method as you must provide an index; however, you can just append, join the resulting list, and write to the file:

```
text_file = open(r"text_file path", "r")
lines = text_file.read().split(',')
lines.insert(0, "String Values Before")
lines.append("String Values After")
text_file.close()
new_file = open('text_file_path.txt', 'w')
new_file.write(','.join(lines)+'\n')
new_file.close()
```